# Can I pad each automatically generated line box in a paragraph of text?

Tags: css

With a background applied to inline text, how can I add padding to the start and end of each line, inside each of the black line boxes? Obviously it needs to be responsive, so it needs to work automatically as the text reflows on narrower or wider screens.

[image]

My desired result looks like this:

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/775/1500);
  background-size: cover;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10vw;
  padding-right: 10vw;
}
span {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p><span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur tincidunt felis at mauris pellentesque aliquam. Morbi rutrum gravida lacus quis ultricies. Vivamus vel mollis purus. Donec tempus nisi id diam posuere eleifend. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed elementum erat eget orci pharetra, in vehicula nulla euismod. Integer blandit, orci et euismod sodales, eros tortor molestie urna, id consectetur nisl risus vulputate velit.
</span></p>
```